# Golang multiple-value http.Get() in single-value context

Tags: golang

Не могу понять почему компилятор выдает ошибку `multiple-value http.Get() in single-value context`
Код:

```
func http_crack() {

    //full-headers example

    //  HTTP/1.x 200 OK
    //  Date: Sat, 12 Dec 2009 15:41:52 GMT
    //  Server: Apache/2.0.61 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.0.61 OpenSSL/0.9.8k mod_dp20/0.99.2 PHP/5.2.5 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.5.1 mod_ruby/1.2.6 Ruby/1.8.6(2007-09-24)
    //  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.5
    //  Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=ft47gokfee6amv3eda3k1p93s3; path=/
    //  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    //  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    //  Pragma: no-cache
    //  Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=1024
    //  Connection: Keep-Alive
    //  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    //  Content-Type: text/html

    response := http.Get(os.Args[1])
    response.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2a1pre) Gecko")
    response.Header.Set("Referer", "http://127.0.0.1/foo-bar/index.html")
    response.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; param=value")

    t_time := time.Now()

    if response.StatusCode == 200 {
        fmt.Println(t.Format(time.RFC3339), "OK")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(t.Format(time.RFC3339), "BAD")
    }



}
```

Как её обойти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод http.Get возвращает *2 значения* объект response, и error, чтобы компилятор корректно обработал вызов этого метода следует определить 2 переменные для получения значений

```
resp, err := http.Get(os.args[1])
```